# MVVM Messenger Register / Send Message in VB.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, mvvm-light, messenger

I just need some Help translating from C# to VB.Net in this Case.

I try to learn about MVVM and WPF. I need to communicate between multiple Views. An easy way should be via MvvmLight Messaging.
Unfortunately all Examples I could find are in C# and the Converter does not understand all of the Code.

What I have:

Register A Message

```
Messenger.Default.Register<GoToPageMessage>( this,( action ) => ReceiveMessage( action ) );

private object ReceiveMessage( GoToPageMessage action )
{
 
   MsgBox( action.PageName );
 
   return null;
}
```

Which the Converter can not translate.

Send a Message:

```
Private Function GoToPage2() As Object

        Dim msg = New GoToPageMessage() With {
            .PageName = "Page2"
        }
        Messenger.[Default].Send(Of GoToPageMessage)(msg)
        Return Nothing
    End Function`
```

The Message Class:

```
 Public Class GoToPageMessage
        Public Property PageName As String
 End Class
```

Can Anyone please take a Look at this and maybe translate all to VB.Net?
I understand most of it, but not the `action` Part. Never heard of this in VB.Net.

Thanks already for all the Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in VB.NET:

```
Private Function ReceiveMessage(action As GoToPageMessage) As Object
    MsgBox(action.PageName)
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

And the registration:

```
Messenger.Default.Register(Of GoToPageMessage)(Me, Sub(x) ReceiveMessage(x))
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I was looking for this a very long Time.